# How do I set a value for a <select> with React without using onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select

I got the following HTML select element

```
<select id="bars" onChange={(e) => onBarChange(e)}>
  {props.results.map((bar, y) => (
    <option value={bar.id} key={bar.id} data-key={bar.id}>
      {bar.name} in {bar.city}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>;
```

with the following onChange method as a callback:

```
const onBarChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
  setBarId(parseInt(e.target.value));
};
```

However, whenever theres only **one** bar in `props.results` (props.results.length === 1) then `onBarChange(e)` will never be called and thus `barId` will always remain 0 (default select value I guess).

I tried to put that logic into the submit form like following:

```js
if(props.results.length === 1) {
  setBarId(props.results[0].id)
}
```

but that isn't working either. If I console log `props.results[0].id` I get the correct id but if I console log `barId` right after this its still 0 again. How can that happen? Is a rerender triggered and the select immediately sets the default 0 as the state again?

How can I resolve this so the submit button wrapping this select is sending the correct barId to the backend whenver theres just one bar in `props.results` (should of course also work with multiple bars..)?

Comment: `setBarId` is asynchronous, so you cannot log right after calling it. But when you do call it ,the component will re-render and then it will have the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating barId using useState pass default value.

```
const [barId, setBarId] = useState(props?.results[0]?.id ?? 0)


const onBarChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setBarId(parseInt(e.target.value));
};


<select id="bars" onChange={(e) => onBarChange(e)}>
    {props.results.map((bar, y) => (
        <option value={bar.id} key={bar.id} data-key={bar.id}>
            {bar.name} in {bar.city}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>;
```

Another thing you can do is add an empty value first.

```
<select id="bars" onChange={(e) => onBarChange(e)}>
    <option>Select Bar</option>
    {props.results.map((bar, y) => (
        <option value={bar.id} key={bar.id} data-key={bar.id}>
            {bar.name} in {bar.city}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>;
```